# Typescript throws an error with latest styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a project which uses React, TypeScript and styled-components. I've been working on this project for a while and then decided to upgrade styled-components to the latest version, which is `5.1.1` (it was `2.4.1` before).
So, the project compiles and runs normally, but when I try to actually build it, it throws these errors:

```
node_modules/@types/styled-components/ts3.7/index.d.ts:151:69 - error TS2694: 
Namespace '"C:/path/node_modules/hoist-non-react-statics/index"' has no exported member 'NonReactStatics'.

151     string & StyledComponentBase<C, T, O, A> & 
hoistNonReactStatics.NonReactStatics<C extends React.ComponentType<any> ? C : never>;
```

```
node_modules/@types/styled-components/ts3.7/index.d.ts:253:65 - error TS2344: 
Type 'C' does not satisfy the constraint 'ComponentType<any>'.
  Type 'ElementType<any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>'.
    Type '"symbol"' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<any>'.
      Type 'C' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.
        Type 'ElementType<any>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.
          Type '"symbol"' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<any>'.

253     ? React.ComponentPropsWithRef<StyledComponentInnerComponent<C>>
```

I tried defferent versions of TypeScript, older versions of styled-components, newer version of Node.js but all of this just gives me a variety of errors. Some setup throws just two errors, other throws 15.
I can attach my `tsconfig.json` if it helps to understand the problem.
My TypeScript version is currently `3.7.`

In my understanding, there are some incompatibilities inside packages that styled-components uses for its needs. But I have no idea how to fix them.